# What means "null!" in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I'm looking to create an angular directive inspired in the [ngxs/form-plugin](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/packages/form-plugin/src/directive.ts)

Searching their code I found something interesting:

```
@Input('ngxsForm')
  path: string = null!;
```

Why is the negation character at the end of the **null**?

Comment: That isn't JavaScript

Comment: @MarcSances Even when applied to a literal value, as here?

Comment: An extra wrinkle: `null!` in TypeScript is a "non-null `null`", which is impossible. The type of `null!` is [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never), the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), and is assignable to all other types. Thus TypeScript will allow you use `null!` for a value of any type, such as `string` above. This is, of course, lying to the compiler; `null` is not a `string` at runtime. If you *want* to lie to the compiler and, e.g., pretend to initialize a class property when you haven't, `null!` is a terse way to do it.

Comment: I wish this would be reopened; the question this supposedly duplicates is asking what `!` is in general, whereas this is specifically about `null!`.  It's like "Q: Why did Michael Jackson wear his trademark single white glove? A: Gloves protect and comfort hands against cold or heat, damage by friction, abrasion or chemicals, and disease; or in turn to provide a guard for what a bare hand should not touch."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` is a typescript operator that asserts an expression is not `null`. This is called the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) and was added as a shorthand to silence strict null checking. The effect of `!` is basically to take `null` out of the type of the expression it is applied to. So for example:

```
declare let x: string | null;
let y = x! // string
```

Normally `path: string = null` would not be valid since `path` is `string` and can't have `null` assigned to it. The type of `null!` is `never` since we are telling the compiler to take `null` out of the type of `null` we are left with no type which is `never`. As the sub-type of every type `never` is assignable to `string`

What we end up with is a field (`path`) that has a type that forbids `null` that is assigned in effect `null`. Such is the nature of assertions, they force the compiler to accept things it knows are invalid. Sometimes this is useful if the field is initialized by some other means, not sure about the exact use case you encountered.