# What does null! mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I got error on:

```
 user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
```

but:

```
user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null!);
```

was not an error. What is the the use of `null!` in this context?

Comment: `!` is the non-null assertion operator, so that's definitely a mistake.

Comment: If you want your behavior subject to allow both `User`s and `null`s, then the right way to do it is `user = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null)`

Comment: I'm reopening this because `null!` is actually a fairly common idiom for pretending that you have a value of type `never`, which is assignable to every type.  At runtime the value will be `null`, so you are 100% lying to the compiler.  But sometimes it's useful to do this.  I need to collect use cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/58592161/5468463

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592161/what-means-null-in-typescript but that was unfortunately closed as a duplicate itself, even though it really isn't.  There's a fairly big semantic difference between `foo!` meaning that `foo` is asserted to be non-null and `null!` meaning that *`null` itself* is asserted to be non-null.

Comment: @samerazeagvvl could you articulate what you are trying to do?  The question "why would someone write `null!` in TypeScript" is a good one, but the way it's written here it's not clear if that's what you're asking because you haven't provided a [mre].  Neither `BehaviorSubject` nor `User` are defined here.  Could you give us enough info to answer?